# NCO/CDO average between specified dates

Tags: netcdf, nco

I have a bunch of netcdf files with multiple daily values of a variable in each file (3 months per file). I want to calculate monthly averages and save to new netcdf files. How to do so using NCO (preferably) or CDO automatically for a large number of years?

ncra for example accepts index numbers for the time steps but the time steps would vary per month (with different number of days and year.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you tell us what you have tried? Googling "CDO monthly average" throws up many hits. Do the standard CDO methods not work with this data?

Comment: I am familiar with NCO but not really with CDO. ncra, which is the typical NCO operator used for time-averaging, accepts index numbers for the time steps. But in my case the time steps would vary per month (with different number of days per month, leap years etc), and the number of years (20) and files/variables is too large to do so manually. I though to run a loop on the month and year, but I could not find a command to time-average between specified dates in CDO or NCO. I can do it in python but this is for many TBs of data and I think it would be quicker in NCO/CDO.

Comment: I’m slightly confused. As I said if you google ‘CDO monthly average’ you can quickly find how to do this. Have you at a minimum googled the problem?

Comment: Seems like you are right and "cdo monmean in.nc out.nc" should do it. Testing it now with my dataset. 
p.s.
I have searched CDO commands before but for some reason was under the impression that monmean and similar commands calculate a climatology.

Comment: It is better to include that information about what you have tried, or your understanding of how methods work, in the question and avoid the impression that you haven't done any research.